# Unified Type System - Any, AnyRef, AnyVal in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to learn scala types.
I am learning from below website.

http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/

Under the topic.
Unified Type System - `Any`, `AnyRef`, `AnyVal`

```
class Person

val allThings = ArrayBuffer[Any]()

val myInt = 42             // Int, kept as low-level `int` during runtime

allThings += myInt         // Int (extends AnyVal)
                           // has to be boxed (!) -> becomes java.lang.Integer in the collection (!)

allThings += new Person()  // Person (extends AnyRef), no magic here
```

When i tried the above code in scala worksheet.
I am getting error in the 2nd line.

```
val allThings = ArrayBuffer[Any]() as value error: value ArrayBuffer
```

Please find my code in scala worksheet.

```
object test1 {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")

  class Person

  val allThings = ArrayBuffer[Any]()

  val myInt = 42             // Int, kept as low-level `int` during runtime

  allThings += myInt         // Int (extends AnyVal)
                           // has to be boxed (!) -> becomes java.lang.Integer in the collection (!)

  allThings += new Person()  // Person (extends AnyRef), no magic here

}
```

Please help me.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Hi Boris thanks i have added val allThings = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any]() and it worked

Comment: As that seemed to fix the problem, I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR: You need to either `import` `ArrayBuffer` of use the FQCN.

**FQCN**

`ArrayBuffer` is not one of your classes, it is a `class` in the Scala library, it lives at `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer`. `scala.collection.mutable` is not one of the packages imported by default:

- java.lang._
- scala._
- scala.Predef._

So in order to use it you need to use the Fully Qualified Class Name:

```
val allThings = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any]()
```

**Importing**

You can tell Scala that you wish to refer to `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer` as simply `ArrayBuffer`, this is called an **import**.

You need to add the following code before your code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
```

Then whenever you use `ArrayBuffer`, the compiler will use `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer`.